# Cannot read property childNodes of null

Tags: javascript

Why do  I get the error cannot read property childNodes of null? This code is obtained from the book SAMS Teach Yourself Javascript in 24 hours.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <script>
    var text = "";
    var pElement = document.getElementById("toDoNotes");
    for (var i=0; i < pElement.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (pElement.childNodes[i].nodeType ==3){
        text += pElement.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
        };
        }
    alert("The paragraph says:\n\n" + text);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Things To Do</h1>
    <ol id="toDoList">
        <li>Mow the lawn</li>
        <li>Clean the windows</li>
        <li>Answer your email</li>
    </ol>
    <p id="toDoNotes">Make sure all these are completed by 8pm so you can watch the game on TV!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code needs to be executed after the page is completely loaded. You can use the [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event to do this.

Your script is added to the `head` element, and this will get executed before the `toDoNotes` element is added to the dom. Thus `document.getElementById("toDoNotes")` will return a null value.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <script>
        function init(){

            var text = "";
            var pElement = document.getElementById("toDoNotes");
            for (var i=0; i < pElement.childNodes.length; i++) {
                if (pElement.childNodes[i].nodeType ==3){
                text += pElement.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
                };
                }
            alert("The paragraph says:\n\n" + text);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <h1>Things To Do</h1>
    <ol id="toDoList">
        <li>Mow the lawn</li>
        <li>Clean the windows</li>
        <li>Answer your email</li>
    </ol>
    <p id="toDoNotes">Make sure all these are completed by 8pm so you can watch the game on TV!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

The JavaScript function is executed before DOM are created. Include the script tag at the end before body tag ended.

YOUR CODE:

```
<head>
<script></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

CORRECT WAY:

```
<head>
// Not here
</head>

<body>
<!-- right before <body> tag is closed -->
<script></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Because, when your JS is executed, your DOM objects are not created yet. So put your script after the body.

```
</body>
<script>
    //---your JS code---
</script>
</html>
```