# Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined in SVG file

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

That error is generally caused by a script executed before the end of the loading of the page as explain here : [Cannot read property childNodes of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199817/cannot-read-property-childnodes-of-null)

But I don't think that it's my error here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg onload="init(evt)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <script xlink:href="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"/>
    <script xlink:href="test.js"/>
    <g id="id">

    </g>
</svg>
```

And the test.js file :

```
function init () {
    $(document).mousedown(test)
}

function test (evt) {
    $('#id').append('test');
    $('#id').append('<rect x=10 y=10 width=50 height=50/>');
}
```

What is curious is that the first appending works but not the second one. Actually the error is raise when there is an `<` in the string... So why ?

Comment: Probably because it tries to use `.innerHTML` in an SVG document, which can't work. Use `document.createElement("rect")`. Could you please post the stack trace of the error you're receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you instantiate the element via the jQuery `$('<tag_name/>')` method, it works.

```
function test (evt) {
  $('#id').append('test');
  $('#id').append($('<rect/>').attr({'x':10,'y':10,'width':50,'height':50}));
}
```